# Cannot read property 'range' of undefined when using the Mapbox Visual in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

I've added a Mapbox visual (latest version 1.5.0) to my PowerBI Report and added a Location, Latitude, Longitude, Size and Cluster fields.

In the format I've enabled Circle and Cluster.

Now, when opening the report in Edge/Chrome the map is displayed but the Clusters and Circles aren't visible. In the console, I see the error in VM986:16.

[image: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined]

When clicking on a Bar Chart Visible on the report or changing some slicer values it displays the Clusters and Circles.
When using the show as a table displays also the correct data.

I've remove the format "Cluster" and then it's working but I cannot find any reason why it's giving this error.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a stacktrace of this error?

From what you describe this sounds as if you're using a non-numeric value in the `cluster` data field.